# How is an inheritance taxed in the United States?

Tags: united-states, taxes, inheritance

My wife will be receiving an inheritance from her Uncle's estate. What are the federal tax implications?

Comment: While this question is about _Federal_ tax implications for the beneficiary for which the answer is that no tax is due _from the beneficiary_ on the inheritance regardless of the size of the inheritance (estate taxes, if any, (both Federal and State) are paid by the estate, not the beneficiaries), some **States** tax _inheritances_ as described in [this recent article](http://www.fool.com/how-to-invest/personal-finance/taxes/2013/05/18/these-6-states-tax-inheritances-the-hardest.aspx). Many don't tax immediate family members (spouses, children etc), but all 6 states mentioned _do_ tax nieces.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on how big the inheritance was. [According to the IRS](http://www.irs.gov/businesses/small/article/0,,id=164871,00.html) you are in the clear unless the total assets she inherits exceed $1 Million.

Edit - In 2013, the amount one can leave and have no federal estate tax issue is $5.25M. It's the deceased's estate that pays the tax, not the beneficiary. So even if this were above the number, it's received post-tax. The article linked above is current.

Comment: So the good news is no taxes, the bad news is that it will be much less than $1M. =)

Comment: The $1M cap is for the estate.   If 4 siblings each inherit $300K, the estate would owe estate tax because it is over the IRS cap.

Comment: @Alex B - True, but in any event isn't the executor responsible for paying out those taxes from the estate rather than the person receiving the inheritance?

Comment: Indeed, John, beneficiaries should see no tax bill at all, the estate pays any tax due. But. For retirement accounts with pretax money, withdrawals are subject to income tax.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer Since you edited JohnFx's answer very recently, you might be interested in my comment on the main question in which I point out that some states tax _inheritances_ quite separately from any estate taxes.  And yes, this has nothing to do with the _question_ itself which is about Federal taxation, not State taxation, of inheritances.

Comment: @DilipSarwate - thanks, yes, when I stumble across answers that are impacted by new rules, I try to update where appropriate, for new viewers. We need Fed/State estate tax wiki/faq here.

Comment: If any of the inheritance is in non-cash assets (stocks, jewelry, art, etc.), wouldn't the beneficiary also need to track value at date of death for reporting capital gains/losses at the eventual time of sale?